# irregular time series: last data point in series

Tags: r

In a previous question ([for loop in irregular time series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25950402/for-loop-in-irregular-time-series)) I presented a dataframe (see the dput below) where  user rnso gave the following, which works quite well for me.

```
for(ss in unique(mydf$site_id)){
  for(cc in 3:12){
    # do whatever function
    print(max(mydf[mydf$site_id == ss, cc],na.rm=TRUE))
  } }

> [1] 304 [1] 16.8 [1] 8.43 [1] 286 [1] 2 [1] 36 [1] 93 [1] 30 [1] 5.98
> [1] 69 [1] -38 [1] 14.7 [1] 7.85 [1] 515 [1] 2 [1] 18 [1] 180 [1] 106
> [1] 0.1 [1] 655'
```

I have been using

```
idx <- max(seq(along=data)) 
lastx <- signif(data[idx], digits=3)
```

to identify the last data point for each mydf[ss,cc], which works well.

Question: how can I further subset mydf[idx] to pull out the date for each idx? I've tried bunches of permutations, and usually get some flavor of "incorrect dimensions" error. 
thanks all!

#### data:

```
mydf <- structure(list(site_id = c("39ADA00070", "39ADA00070", "39ADA00070", 
"39ADA00070", "39ADA00070", "39ADA00070", "39ADA00070", "39ADA00070", 
"39ADA00070", "39ADA00070", "39ADA00070", "39ADA00070", "39ADA00070", 
"39ADA00070", "39ADA00070", "39ADA00070", "39ADA00070", "39ADA00070", 
"39ADA00070", "39ADA00070", "39ADA00070", "39ADA00070", "39ADA00070", 
"39ADA00070", "39ADA00070", "39ADA00070", "39ADA00070", "39ADA00070", 
"39ADA00070", "39ADA00070", "39ALL00184", "39ALL00184", "39ALL00184", 
"39ALL00184", "39ALL00184", "39ALL00184", "39ALL00184", "39ALL00184", 
"39ALL00184", "39ALL00184", "39ALL00184", "39ALL00184", "39ALL00184", 
"39ALL00184", "39ALL00184", "39ALL00184", "39ALL00184", "39ALL00184", 
"39ALL00184", "39ALL00184", "39ALL00184", "39ALL00184", "39ALL00184"
), date = structure(c(6339, 8594, 9293, 9441, 10014, 10604, 11080, 
11821, 12717, 12907, 13081, 13277, 13459, 13635, 13822, 14012, 
14207, 14207, 14355, 14564, 14704, 14917, 15105, 15271, 15478, 
15644, 15833, 15834, 16009, 16203, 7783, 8406, 8554, 8686, 9034, 
9260, 9632, 9777, 10002, 10491, 10491, 11060, 11585, 12145, 12145, 
12696, 13242, 13242, 13775, 14363, 14881, 15428, 15974), class = "Date"), 
    var1 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 159L, 148L, 
    149L, 134L, 179L, 205L, 193L, 109L, 109L, 177L, 75L, 272L, 
    150L, 115L, 232L, 230L, 183L, 159L, 159L, 304L, 220L, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    -98L, -98L, -38L, -74L, -74L, -80L, -48L), var2 = c(NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 16.8, 16.8, 14.5, 14.2, 15.1, 14.5, 
    15, 15.2, 13.2, 13.2, 15, 15.2, 15.1, 14.4, 14.8, 15.2, 16.3, 
    NA, 14.3, 14.3, 15.6, 14.8, NA, 12, 14.7, NA, 14.6, NA, 13.7, 
    12.3, 12.5, 13.5, 13.5, 12.5, 13.1, 14.2, 14.2, 14.1, 12.5, 
    12.5, 13.5, 12.7, 12.6, 12.5, 12.6), var3 = c(NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 7.35, 7.85, 7.5, 7.47, 7.62, 7.08, 7.08, 
    7.2, 7.4, 7.4, 7.26, 7.05, 6.56, 7.2, 7.42, 6.5, 7.81, 8.43, 
    7.57, 7.57, 7.42, 7.72, NA, 6.58, 6.8, NA, 7.75, NA, 7.06, 
    6.77, 6.41, 6.84, 6.84, 7.85, 7.13, 7.26, 7.26, 7.06, 7.14, 
    7.14, 7.11, 6.9, 7.11, 7.2, 7.1), var4 = c(NA, 283L, 216L, 
    223L, 256L, 165L, 192L, 216L, 173L, 216L, 179L, 282L, 146L, 
    227L, 141L, 210L, 160L, 162L, 157L, 140L, 235L, 166L, 216L, 
    NA, 162L, 193L, 286L, 274L, 163L, 209L, NA, 304L, 321L, 293L, 
    398L, 302L, 301L, 282L, 288L, 292L, 292L, 302L, 515L, 309L, 
    309L, 323L, 338L, 295L, 280L, 279L, 325L, 328L, 322L), var5 = c(NA, 
    NA, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), var6 = c(NA, NA, 
    29L, 32L, 36L, 24L, 25L, 29L, 27L, 27L, 24L, 32L, 21L, 27L, 
    21L, 26L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 20L, 24L, 22L, 28L, 24L, 20L, 23L, 
    30L, 29L, 21L, 24L, 15L, 15L, 18L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 
    15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 
    15L, 15L, 15L), var7 = c(NA, NA, 77, 83, 87, 66, 73, 73, 
    65, 76, 69, 93, 60, 76, 56, 77, 67, 68, 68, 60, 67, 63, 82, 
    69, 56, 68, 85, 83, 59, 68.2, 157, 159, 164, 169, 155, 176, 
    156, 156, 162, 162, 162, 160, 180, 163, 163, 158, 168, 171, 
    162, 167, 177, 167, 168), var8 = c(NA, NA, 25, 26, 29, 21, 
    22, 23, 20, 23, 21, 30, 17, 24, 16, 23, 20, 20, 21, 17, 23, 
    18, 25, 20, 17, 21, 27, 27, 17, 20.9, 91, 89, 96, 92, 86, 
    100, 89, 91, 92, 94, 94, 91, 97, 91, 91, 92, 98, 99, 94, 
    100, 106, 98, 100), var9 = c(1.02, 1, 0.37, 0.48, 0.88, 0.16, 
    0.17, 0.24, 0.25, 5.98, 0.26, 0.54, 0, 0.19, 0, 0.18, 0.14, 
    0.13, 0.16, 0.11, 0.19, 0.16, 0.26, NA, 0.11, 0.27, 0.19, 
    0.19, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, NA, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 
    0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0, 0, 0.1, 0.1, 
    0.1), var10 = c(50, 48, 64, 55, 52, 64, 69, 63.3, 56.1, 40.6, 
    58.6, 43.9, 62.2, 51.9, 55.6, 53.4, 61.3, 61, 61.1, 61.9, 
    51.5, 60.7, 52.2, NA, 66, 52.8, 46.8, 47.5, 59.2, 53.4, NA, 
    560, 650, 540, 548, 655, 565, 531, 540, 501, 501, 531, 535, 
    547, 547, 492, 537, 542, 512, 542, 548, 581, 540)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-53L), .Names = c("site_id", "date", "var1", "var2", "var3", 
"var4", "var5", "var6", "var7", "var8", "var9", "var10"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here how I would do this:

```
library(data.table)
library(reshape2)
dcast(melt(setDT(mydf),id.vars='site_id')
      [,max(value,na.rm=TRUE),'site_id,variable'],
      site_id ~variable)

     site_id  date var1 var2 var3 var4 var5 var6 var7 var8 var9 var10
1 39ADA00070 16203  304 16.8 8.43  286    2   36   93   30 5.98    69
2 39ALL00184 15974  -38 14.7 7.85  515    2   18  180  106 0.10   655
```

1. I am using data.table for grouping operations
2. put your data in the long format since you do to perform the same operation in many columns
3. for each variable( even dates) get the maximum value
4. reshape your data again to the wide format using dcast.

Comment: very slick and concise @agstudy. Forcing me to expand my horizons  big time - I WILL dig into data.table and reshape to see how you've done what you did. Is there anyway you could take a look at the more classical subscript, since my working script is a straight nested for-loop (mydf[mydf$site_id == ss, cc])? How can I reach across the frame and get the associated "date" for idx <- max(seq(along=data))? Thanks again for your great input!